# Image.Source (with binding) is blocking image file after binding is removed

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

In a `GridView`, I've templated the items so an Image control inside that template receives an Uri  using a binding (also tried with BitmapImage) to show a picture file. It works, but I cannot delete those files because those files are blocked.  Even if I clear the collection feeding the `GridView.ItemsSource`, and even if I call `GC.Collect()`, they are still blocked.

Thanks to Philip for his working suggestion... as I used a Converter to feed a BitmapImage to every Image control, found some particular things had to do to make it work, and here it is for future reference:

```
InMemoryRandomAccessStream Ras = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
var archivo = CartoonsDownloader.FolderImagenes.GetFileAsync(TheFileName);

var fileStream = CartoonsDownloader.FolderImagenes.OpenStreamForReadAsync(TheFileName);
fileStream.Result.CopyTo(Ras.AsStreamForWrite());

BitmapImage MapaDeBits = new BitmapImage();
// Even it's RANDOM, I have to manually "Seek" it at 0.
Ras.Seek(0);
MapaDeBits.SetSource(Ras);
MapaDeBits.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreImageCache;
return MapaDeBits;
```

Comment: Out of curiosity - how do you set the Uri to get an image from a location that supports deleting files?

Comment: This way: ms-appdata:///local/My Cartoons/Images/image.jpg, check this nice post for a complete list of uri syntaxes for Metro: http://lunarfrog.com/blog/2012/05/21/winrt-folders-access/#local

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be a bug in the XAML stack (so you could report it on MSDN [forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/threads)), or just a side effect of its nature of caching images. As an alternative - you can open the file yourself and set the image using the [SetSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.bitmapsource.setsource.aspx) method. Then you should have better control over the file access.